# tableprint.table only works with randomized numbers

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to practice using tableprint by making a basic table, but I'm finding it difficult to input my own numbers (the only time I can make a table is when the numbers are randomized). Any help is appreciated.

```
import tableprint as tp
import numpy as np 

m=np.array([1,2,3,4])

n=np.random.randn(10, 4)
headers= ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
tp.table(n, headers) #works
tp.table(m, headers) #does not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tableprint.table`](https://tableprint.readthedocs.io/#api) takes a **2D** array as first parameter, your array `m` is only **1D**.

> data : array_like
> An (m x n) array containing the data to print (m rows of n columns)

So you need to convert `m` to a 2D array:

```
tp.table(m[np.newaxis], headers)
```

Result:

```
╭───────┬───────┬───────┬───────╮
│ name1 │ name2 │ name3 │ name4 │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│     1 │     2 │     3 │     4 │
╰───────┴───────┴───────┴───────╯
```